# How do I refer to this control in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I wrote this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='textarea']")).sendKeys("foo");
```

and I got this

```
BrowserController.remoteControl(): Unable to locate element: //input[@type='textarea']
```

[image: Here is the page source]

Comment: Use `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='textarea']"))` and see if there are multiple elements matching ?

Comment: did you switch the driver to a frame or something? if that is the case you need to switch back to default content.

Comment: @UlugToprak No, I did not switch the driver.

Comment: you could use firebug in Firefox to copy the xpath i suppose.

Comment: @nicomp Why exactly do you need to refer to this control? What is your business case?

Comment: @DebanjanB I can tell you that I am developing a Java desktop app that needs to talk to Firefox tab in which a Neo4j client is loaded. So I want to inject commands into the browser tab.

Comment: Sounds great !!! Isn't Firefox tab completely at your disposal? You mentioned about the `textarea`. Anyways, JS would be of your help.

Comment: @DebanjanB Yes I can open the Firefox tab and control it. I don't see how JS could help. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

When you are not able to find the element it could be following reasons

1. **Identifier** you provided is wrong
2. **element is inside some frame**, in this case you will have to find that frame and switch to it.

   > driver.switchTo().frame(1);
3. website is taking sometime to load the element. in this case you could you explicit wait.

   > wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("id"));